# Get router or computer to share bandwidth equally amongst applications

Tags: router, bandwidth

16Mbps is available via my cable-based ISP. When FileZilla is used to download a movie or television show via FTP, all 16Mbps of bandwidth are used. This is the expected and desired behavior.

The problem is that other network apps that are running in parallel with the download are left with virtually zero bandwidth. Whether that secondary application be a browser on the same machine, an Ethernet-connected AppleTV on the same network, or a guest browsing wirelessly on his laptop, virtually no bandwidth is available for the duration of the FileZilla download.

What I would (perhaps naively) expect to happen is:

(1) If the AppleTV requires 2Mbps to do it's job, it would get it's 2Mbps and the FileZilla download would be degraded to 14Mbps.

(2) If ten people entered my house and all started downloading from the Internet, each one of them would have access to 1.6 Mbps (16 Mbps divided by 10 people).

But this isn't what happens at all. The FileZilla download somehow consumes all external bandwidth that's available to the network.

Shouldn't my LinkSys E1000 router be able to give each outbound TCP/IP connection it's own share of the bandwidth? I double-checked the router settings and QOS functionality is turned off.

** I realize that I could artificially cap FileZilla's bandwidth usage in the user settings but that's not what I want. If FileZilla is the only app running on the network, it truly should have access to all 16Mbps. It feels like it's the router that should be responsible for giving each app its fair share but maybe that's just not how routers work? Please help.

Comment: 1. The E1000 does support QOS, although admittedly I've never used it. 2. You can enable `speed limits` in the FileZilla client settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't my LinkSys E1000 router be able to give each outbound TCP/IP connection it's own share of the bandwidth? I double-checked the router settings and QOS functionality is turned off.

No. The router has no control over what packets your ISP puts on the wire to you. QoS won't give it control over that.

> It feels like it's the router that should be responsible for giving each app its fair share but maybe that's just not how routers work?

No, that's not how routers work. Your router just routes the packets it receives from the rest of the world. It has no control over what it receives or how data gets put on the wire from your ISP to your router.

No significant effort has been put into make residential Internet access support any notion of "fairness" within the available bandwidth for an individual customer. There do exist some routers that fake it with technologies like [StreamBoost](http://www.qca.qualcomm.com/products/qualcomm-streamboost/), but they are the exception.

Comment: Thank you. This helps. But in a world where an FTP site is pushing data to me at a high rate, and Apple is simultaneously pushing data to me at 2Mbps, and my total bandwidth available is 16Mbps, and my router just takes the packets as they come with no prioritization logic whatsoever (as you describe), doesn't it seem odd that virtually all of the inbound packets are from the FTP site and Apple is being crowded out? Wouldn't we expect a more balanced distribution, even if no prioritization logic is applied at the router level? It's not an urgent thing but now you've got me curious!

Comment: @ChadDecker Sure, you would expect that, and sometimes that happens. But nothing tries to make it happen. So it can also not happen. I can also argue that once your full bandwidth is in use, the new connection will see almost no available bandwidth and will never send anywhere near it's fair share. Both arguments are reasonable. (Also, you mean 2MB/s, not 2Mbps. Your line is 16Mbps, which can support a download of about 2MB/s -- actually, 1.91)

Comment: Chad that's what QOS is for... You determine the priority of the packets comming into the router to what devices you want

Comment: @Ramhound By the time his router has received the packets, the earliest QOS could do anything about it, it's already too late. The bandwidth has already been consumed. The QoS would have to be done by his ISP's router, as *it* controls what's put on the wire to him. (QoS works when a router is handling packets received on a fast link and sent on a slow link. There you can prioritize what you put on the slow link. But he has the reverse situation. QoS can't help him.)

Answer (score 0):

Most DSL modems don't offer this functionality but if you can dedicate a low spec PC and some time you can install [pfsense](http://pfsense.org/) and configure it like this:

### pfSense configuration

Go to **firewall > Traffic Shaper > Limiters**

Create a *New Limiter*(8) for the **download** of WAN1 named like *LimWan1Down*. Just set its Bandwidth to a bit(5) bellow the *download BW* of your WAN(3) (preferably(1) in multiplies of 64kbps). Don't go bellow 256Kbps(6)

Save the limiter and click the option to *Add a New Queue*(7) to create a queue named like *QueWan1Down* and just set its mask to "**destination** addresses".

Create another Limiter for the *upload* of WAN1 named like *LimWan1Up*. Just set its Bandwidth to a bit bellow the *upload BW* of your WAN* (preferably in multiplies of 64kbps). Don't go bellow 256Kbps(6)

Save the limiter and click the option to *Add a New Queue* to create a queue named like *QueWan1Up* and just set its mask to "**source** addresses".

Finally go to *firewall > rules > LAN* and find the rule(2) that pass trafic to WAN1. Click edit and go to *advanced settings > In / Out pipe* and specify your *Upload Queue* in the *first (In)* part and your *Download Queue* in the *second (Out)* part(9).

Don't forget to click *Apply Changes*.

Now the limiters will keep the total upload or download BW from all of your clients limited so that we avoid unwanted buffering at the ISP side while the queues distribute that limited BW evenly between all the LAN clients (LAN IPs to be precise).

To test immidiately you must first go to **Diagnostics > States > Reset States** and click *Reset* but beware that *everybodys TCP connections we'll be reset* (that includes your connection to the WebUI).

Now go start some downloads/uploads and check *Diagnostics > Limiter Info.*

This method keeps your RTT times low by limiting your total download and upload bandwidth (thus preventing buffering at the ISP) and shares that BW evenly between you LAN clients. You get a decent browsing/skype/RDP/ssh experience when a lot of users have maxed out your WAN(s), yet it still allows one client to get the full BW when nobody else needs it.

### Quick reference

If you get used to the above procedure and just want a quick reference in order not to mix up the the settings here it is:

```
Pipe | Direction  | Queue mask
-----+------------+--------------------
In   | Upload     | Source Address
Out  | Download   | Destination Address
```

### Notes:

(1): not sure if this is important.

(2): not sure if it works the same when there are many rules because I've only tested with one rule.

(3): if you have multiple WANs you do the above for every WAN but I *believe* that things get tricky because on your firewall each LAN rule that passes traffic should be dealing with a specific WAN(4). in my case when I had 2 WANs I splitted the LAN IPs in even and odd ones and each group was using a specific WAN(with fail over of course). A bit hacky I know. Keep in mind that drakontas doesn't share my worries. He states that "The limiters described here work as expected when used in combination with Gateway Groups (i.e. Multi-WAN) without any additional modification as long as the firewall rules include the Gateway Group as the Gateway (under Advanced)."

(4): I'm 99% sure this is the case but have never tested.

(5): here's how to find how much it's a bit: find a bad day/time for you line where it downloads/uploads at its worst rate. Before enabling anything begin a massive download/upload and look at your ping times going of the roof. Try a setting for the download/upload limit. If your ping times go off the roof you need to lower the limit.

(6) I haven't tested it but I've read this logic: the max size of an IPv4 packet is 64KBytes i.e. 256kbits. So if you go lower the limiter may have to cut packets apart, which results in higher latency, lower throughput, and a poor user experience.

(7) pfsense's UI is a little glitchy at this point. Finish your limiter, save it, click on it's name again and then try to click Add New Queue

(8) the terminology is a little confusing. In this text I've used the terms with caution but you may see the terms limiter, pipe and queue used interchangably.

(9) think of the packets flows from the perspective of the LAN interface. Packets flowing from the local network into the LAN interface will become WAN upload and vice versa.

### Advanced material

These are some advanced notes copied directly from the drakontas reddit post (see credits):

- If using Floating firewall rules instead of per-interface rules, you must have two rules -- one applied to "In" traffic and one applied to "Out" traffic (direction is specified in the rule).
- If you have many users (for example, thousands of devices sharing a relatively small uplink), you will want to increase the advanced "Queue Size" option on each Pipe and Queue (default is 50 if no value is indicated). This allows cleaner handling of user traffic during high congestion periods.
- The advanced "Queue Size" option can be set to a maximum of 100. This is not documented or indicated on the GUI, but if you try to set this value >100, the limiters will throw an error and will not be correctly applied. This can slow down a reboot and also can be a totally hidden error when applied on a running system (the only indication that something is wrong is that the Diagnostics > Limiter Info page will not reflect the new settings, even after resetting states).
- Remember that for TCP flows where ACK responses are required for data integrity, upload is necessary even while downloading (and vice versa). In my tests, restricting upload to 512kbps results in a maximum real-world download speed of 50-60mbps; restricting upload to 256kbps results in a maximum download speed of 20-30mbps (and of course, YMMV) For UDP flows this is irrelevant

### Credits

This article is based on foxale08 series of posts with screenshots [on the pfsense forum](https://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=63531.msg364520#msg364520) (you must login to see the screenshots) and from [the excelent drakontas reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/PFSENSE/comments/3e67dk/flexible_vs_fixed_limiters_troubleshooting_with/)